# VAIO laptop's wireless indicator blinking when connected to access point

Tags: 10.04, wireless, drivers, intel-wireless

I have a VAIO laptop model VGN-C22GH. It has a built in wireless card with a Intel Centrino processor on his motherboard.

When using Ubuntu 10.04, the wireless indicator blinks violently. This symptom does not appear with earlier versions of Ubuntu like 9.10 or 8.10.

This leads me to believe that it is a driver issue. Is it something that I should worry about?

I have no idea where to look for, since this is a very limited scope problem. Should I report to Cannonical about this problem of mine??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Vaio vgnsr190 with Ubuntu 11.10 on it. When i switch on the wireless key <strike>(and it is also the Bluetooth key)</strike> the wireless indicator does not blink, but when i turn off Bluetooth (not with physical key) the wireless indicator starts to blinks.

I think it is not problem or error. It just show that you are connected to network.